# Reference to the Globals.ThisAddIn.Application of project is not Add-In

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in

In solution has multiple projects. One of them - Word Add-In. From the other (not Add-In) to gain access to Globals.ThisAddIn.Application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cant get Globals.ThisAddIn.Application in non Addin project. To get application instance in non addin project you can use

```
 var wordApplication = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem after searching for 2 days